# How can I use 2 bodies in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I’m getting an error message

“The argument for the named parameter ‘body’ was already specified.”

Comment: What is your intention with two bodies? If you need two widgets together at the same time, use them inside the body, and in the body use a Column or a List. You can't have the same parameter twice

Comment: please explain your problem with details

Comment: maybe you should look into Stack

Answer (score 1):

You can't. I'm not sure what you need to do. But here's a list of widgets and Codes that might help you achieve what you want:

**Column widget** :List widgets in a column

```
   body: Column(
      children: [
         Container(), 
         Container(),
         Container()
      ],
    )
```

**Stack widget** :Stack widgets on top of each other

```
   body: Stack(
      children: [
         Container(), 
         Container(),
         Container()
      ],
    )
```

**PageView widget** : Create pages that users can navigate to by swiping the screen left and right

```
   body: PageView(
      children: [
         Container(), 
         Container(),
         Container()
      ],
    )
```